# Twig Cache taking 10s and stuck on Loop

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

Something unusual happened with my site. I'm using slim 4.1. I have implemented twig view cache.
Last night only with 50 active users the site went down.
On checking logs I noticed it keeps on making the cache.

Upon checking with my infra team they said the fpm might got stuck because of repeitively creating the cache.
But still the issue is unknown that why it happened. I am attaching the logs below. Can someone let me know if it is normal or what could be the cause.

Also a suggestion need. I was thinking to eliminate the cache from twig and cache it on server level via nginx. Wouldn't that be optimal ?

[image]

Not Found Handled code:

```
$app->group('', function(RouteCollectorProxy $group){
    $group->get('/{slug:.*}', function($request, $response, array $args) {
        $res = $request->getAttribute('data');
        if(isset($res)) {
            if($res['type'] == 'course') {
                $controllerClass = '\App\Controllers\Frontend\ControllerCommon';
                $method = 'viewPlayer';
            }
            else if($res['type'] == 'category') {
                $controllerClass = '\App\Controllers\Frontend\Controller'.$res['code'];
                if($res['parent_id'] == 0)
                    $method = 'viewParentCategory';
                else
                    $method = 'viewSingleCategory';
            }
            else {
                $controllerClass = '\App\Controllers\Frontend\Controller'.$res['code'];
                if(!empty($res['template'])){
                    $method = $res['template'];
                }
                else {
                    if($res['parent_id'] == 0)
                        $method = 'viewParentPage';
                    else
                        $method = 'viewSinglePage';
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $controllerClass = '\App\Controllers\Frontend\ControllerCommon';
            $method = 'notFound';
        }

        $controller = new $controllerClass($this);
        return call_user_func_array([$controller, $method], func_get_args());
    });
```

My Index.php file

```php
// Instantiate PHP-DI ContainerBuilder
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

if (PRODUCTION) { // container compiled and cached
    $containerBuilder->enableCompilation(API_DIR . '/var/cache');
}

// Set up settings
$settings = require API_DIR . '/libs/settings.php';
$settings($containerBuilder);

// Set up dependencies
$dependencies = require API_DIR . '/libs/dependencies.php';
$dependencies($containerBuilder);

// Set up helper
$helper = require API_DIR . '/libs/Helper.php';

// Build PHP-DI Container instance
$container = $containerBuilder->build();

// Instantiate the app
AppFactory::setContainer($container);
$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->setBasePath(MAIN_DIR);
$callableResolver = $app->getCallableResolver();

// Create Twig
$twig = Twig::create(TEMPLATE_PATH, ['cache' => (PRODUCTION) ? API_DIR . '/var/cache' : false, 'debug' => true]);

// Add Assets Path
$loader = $twig->getLoader();
if ($loader instanceof FilesystemLoader) {
    $loader->addPath($container->get('settings')['assets']['path'], 'public');
}

// Add Asset Extensions
$environment = $twig->getEnvironment();
$twig->addExtension(new TwigAssetsExtension($environment, (array)$container->get('settings')['assets']));

// Add Twig-View Middleware
$app->add(TwigMiddleware::create($app, $twig));

// Register routes
// if (PRODUCTION) { // routes compiled and cached
//     $routeCollector = $app->getRouteCollector();
//     $routeCollector->setCacheFile(API_DIR . '/var/cache/routes.cache.php');
// }
$routes = require API_DIR . '/libs/routes.php';
$routes($app);

// Add Extensions
$twig->addExtension(new TwigExtension($app));

/** @var bool $displayErrorDetails */
$displayErrorDetails = $container->get('settings')['displayErrorDetails'];

// Create Request object from globals
$serverRequestCreator = ServerRequestCreatorFactory::create();
$request = $serverRequestCreator->createServerRequestFromGlobals();

// // Create Error Handler
$responseFactory = $app->getResponseFactory();
$errorHandler = new HttpErrorHandler($callableResolver, $responseFactory);

// Create Shutdown Handler
$shutdownHandler = new ShutdownHandler($request, $errorHandler, $displayErrorDetails);
register_shutdown_function($shutdownHandler);

// Add Routing Middleware
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

// Add Error Middleware
$errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware($displayErrorDetails, false, false);
$errorMiddleware->setDefaultErrorHandler($errorHandler);

// Run App & Emit Response
$response = $app->handle($request);
$responseEmitter = new ResponseEmitter();
$responseEmitter->emit($response);
```

Comment: You need to provide more details, seems the cache doesn't get created because of the route isn't found. Also please don't errors as an image

Comment: nginx caching can't replace Twig's cache

Comment: I agree with @NicoHaase. Twig cache optimizes the rendering of dynamic content generated by your PHP application and Nginx cache optimizes the serving of static and potentially dynamic content to reduce the load on your PHP application server.

Comment: So decide based on your specific application's requirements, server resources, and the trade-offs you're willing to make.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Adi I'll use a mix both to make it work I guess.

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you so much I guess yes this seems to be issue. couple of days earlier there was a url that I got an email from google was not indexed, upon checking, the page didn't exist. I guess maybe its related to that. 
So basically its the same route that isn't found and it keeps trying right ?

Comment: That does not sound related. As you haven't shared any code so far, nor any other information about what the application does when the error occurs, it's impossible to provide help

Comment: For example, keep in mind that Slim 4.1 is more than four years old. Maybe you are facing any bug with that version that was fixed in the meantime?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have edited the post and like DarkBee said, I don't think its the route not found issue. As you can see in the code I'm already handling it. 
If you convert the hexadecimal code on the right side,you will notice it almost took 10s for this stuff. Idk why it keeps going in the loop or stuck somewhere.

Comment: Which parts of that code take so long? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase the image that I shared is basically a log trace that I've added. Anything taking longer than 10s records the trace. Therefore all you see above, the reading of cache etc is something that took longer than 10s which I am not sure why. I am still looking into the root cause but as of now, not sure how it happened.

Comment: Did you check your server's error log? Maybe it contains a hint about the route that was used to trigger the bug